# Load style vsf from resource file not working

Tags: delphi

I am trying to load style vsf file from resource but I get error style does not exists. I tried load from file and it work !

[image]

I tried `RCDATA` and this code

```
TStyleManager.LoadFromResource(HInstance, 'Resource_1');
TStyleManager.SetStyle('Resource_1');
```

But I get error resource Resource_1 does not exists. I tried also with style name but also did not work. where is the problem ?

Comment: I'm not sure what your goal is. Where did you get the resource name (`Resource_1`) from? Based on `Type - Bitmap`, is this related to your previous question regarding VCL Styles?

Comment: No I just want to load from resource file. I get it from resource identifier